# Can I check luggage to both intermediate and final destinations?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, international-travel

I was traveling to from the US to Singapore with an 8 hour stopover in Hong Kong on Cathay Pacific. I checked luggage to the final destination Singapore. I also wanted to check a piece of luggage to Hong Kong only, to give a gift to a friend in Hong Kong not permitted as carry-on. Cathay Pacific did not support this; I could check luggage only to the final destination. For the future, is this possible on other airlines, or is this a policy common to all airlines?

This is not a duplicate of [How to fly to multiple destinations and luggages?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55453/) because I travel with all of the luggage.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of a different question, *[Checking-in bags to different destinations when flying with a layover](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14807/checking-in-bags-to-different-destinations-when-flying-with-a-layover)* The short answer is no. Due to security concerns, airlines will generally not allow you to check a bag for only part of your trip, unless you have an overnight stop somewhere.

Comment: @choster Yes, it looks like my question is a duplicate there. However, your comment response is not among the answers of that question!